# Integrate: $\int \frac{2x^2-3x+8}{x^3+4x} \, dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\int \frac{2x^2-3x+8}{x^3+4x}\,dx$$

My main problem is calculating the $B$ and $C$. This is the algebra part. Thus, what is a technique I can use that is in line with what I did to calculate $A$? [image]

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Comment: The image does not match the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can equate powers of $x$. So you see that your equation simplifies to $$2x^2 -3x+8=Ax^2+4A+Bx^2+Cx$$
If we equate all powers of $x$ we get the system of equations
$$x^2:2=A+B$$
$$x:-3=C$$
$$x^0:8=4A$$

From here it is clear how to get $B,C$.

Comment: How did you get B if A+B =2. How do you get 0?

Comment: If you equate all of the coefficients of $x^2$ on both sides, you get $2 = A + B$ because those are the only coefficients with $x^2$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: I follow to that point; but how did you calculate zero?

Comment: I didn't calculate zero. I think you meant $x^0$. The $x^0$ terms are just the constants that don't have an $x$ infront of them.

Comment: if A= 2 and C= -3 how do calculate B? That is my question.

Comment: Oh, then you have the equation $A+B = 2$ and you can substitute A = 2 into there and you get $2 + B = 2$. So $B=0$.

Comment: Okay. $x^0$ represents all the constants or better yet the coefficients with variables devoid of exponents greater or lesser then zero?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from your work,
$$2x^2-3x+8=A(x^2+4)+(Bx+C)x$$

Now $x=0$ gives $A=2$

Also we can write the above equation as :
$$2x^2-3x+8=(A+B)x^2+4A+Cx$$

This is an identity in $x$.

So coefficients of the respective powers on both sides must be same.

$$A+B=2$$ and $$C=-3$$
So $$B=0$$

Comment: What do you mean by "This is an identity in x"? Can you say this in another way? So far I distributed the $A$ and $x$ on the left side. This gave me $Ax^2+4A+Bx^2+Cx$ How do A+B=2? How does C=-3..Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews Are you wondering how that was calculated also?

Comment: @Cetshwayo Check this link as to what you mean by an identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics) ... I think if you get this idea, the other doubts will then be easily resolved. :-)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That was typo.... Corrected now..

Comment: @Cetshwayo In case you do not understand from the link, both sides of the equation written represent the same expression.  So you equate the coefficients of the terms on both sides. Only then you will get the same expression on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to set $x=2t$ anyway, because of the factor $x^2+4$, do it at the start: the integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{8t^2-6t+8}{4t(t^2+1)}\,2dt
=
\int\frac{4t^2-3t+4}{t(t^2+1)}\,dt
=
\int\left(\frac{4}{t}-\frac{3}{t^2+1}\right)\,dt=4\log|t|-3\arctan t+c
$$
So your original integral is
$$
\int\frac{2x^2-3x+8}{x^3+4x}\,dx=4\log|x|-3\arctan\frac{x}{2}+c
$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying both sides of $$\frac{2x^2-3x+8}{x^3+4x}=\frac Ax+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4}$$
with $x(x^2+4)$, you can remove denominators, and get
$$2x^2-3x+8=A(x^2+4)+(Bx+C)x. $$
Then set $x=\;$ the poles of the fraction:

- $x=0$ yields $8=4A+0$, whence  $A=2$.
- $x=2\mathrm i$  yields $-8-6\mathrm i+8=-6\mathrm i=0+(2B\mathrm i+C)2\mathrm i=-4B+2C\mathrm i$. Identifying the real and imaginary parts, we get
  $$B=0,\enspace C=-3.$$